# How do I implement stochastic gradient descent correctly?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement stochastic gradient descent in MATLAB however I am not seeing any convergence. Mini-batch gradient descent worked as expected so I think that the cost function and gradient steps are correct.

The two main issues I am having are:

1. Randomly shuffling the data in the training set before the
   for-loop
2. Selecting one example at a time

Here is my MATLAB code:

**Generating Data**

```
alpha = 0.001;
num_iters = 10;

xrange =(-10:0.1:10); % data lenght
ydata  = 5*(xrange)+30; % data with gradient 2, intercept 5

% plot(xrange,ydata); grid on;
noise  = (2*randn(1,length(xrange))); % generating noise 
target = ydata + noise; % adding noise to data

f1 = figure
subplot(2,2,1);
scatter(xrange,target); grid on; hold on; % plot a scttaer
title('Linear Regression')
xlabel('xrange')
ylabel('ydata')

tita0 = randn(1,1); %intercept (randomised)
tita1 = randn(1,1); %gradient  (randomised)

% Initialize Objective Function History
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

% Number of training examples
m = (length(xrange));
```

**Shuffling data, Gradient Descent and Cost Function**

```
% STEP1 : we shuffle the data
data = [ xrange, ydata];
data = data(randperm(size(data,1)),:);
y = data(:,1);
X = data(:,2:end);

for iter = 1:num_iters

    for i = 1:m

        x = X(:,i); % STEP2 Select one example

        h = tita0 + tita1.*x; % building the estimated     %Changed to xrange in BGD

        %c = (1/(2*length(xrange)))*sum((h-target).^2)

        temp0 = tita0 - alpha*((1/m)*sum((h-target)));
        temp1 = tita1 - alpha*((1/m)*sum((h-target).*x));  %Changed to xrange in BGD
        tita0 = temp0;
        tita1 = temp1;

        fprintf("here\n %d; %d", i, x)

    end

        J_history(iter) = (1/(2*m))*sum((h-target).^2); % Calculating cost from data to estimate

        fprintf('Iteration #%d - Cost = %d... \r\n',iter, J_history(iter));

end
```

---

On plotting the cost vs iterations and linear regression graphs, the MSE settles (local minimum?) at around 420 which is wrong.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the answer below, my updated code:

```
% STEP1 : we shuffle the data
data = [ xrange' , target'];
data = data(randperm(size(data,1)),:);
y = data(:,1);
X = data(:,2:end);


for iter = 1:num_iters

    for i = 1:m

        x = X(i,:); % STEP2 Select one example

        h = tita0 + tita1.*x; % building the estimated

        %c = (1/(2*length(xrange)))*sum((h-target).^2)

        temp0 = tita0 - alpha*((1/m)*sum((h-y(i))));
        temp1 = tita1 - alpha*((1/m)*sum((h-y(i)).*x));
        tita0 = temp0;
        tita1 = temp1;

        fprintf("here\n %d; %d", i, x)

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fundamentals are wrong in your program:

- Your gradient update is based on `target` variable, but it's not shuffled, and it shouldn't be an array. It should be just a value, because it is the target for $i-$th sample. Suggested correction:

  `tita0 = tita0 - alpha*((1/m)*((h-y(i))));
   tita1 = tita1 - alpha*((1/m)*((h-y(i)).*x));`
- Your `data` array isn't of correct dimension, and it should include `target` instead of `y`, i.e. the noisy observations. Suggested correction:

  `data = [ xrange', target']; 
  data = data(randperm(size(data,1)),:);`

And another one I forgot to mention:

- Your x and y indexings are also wrong:

  `y = data(:,2);
  X = data(:,1);`

Increase your number of iterations, to $10000$, and you'll see that $\theta$ will converge to $[5,30]$. I'm having the correct results, you should be having it after doing these modificaitions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I am not able to get good results with the suggestions above. I agree with both suggestions and my experiment was fundamentally flawed. However I am still shuffling the data incorrectly or selecting one example incorrectly since I keep getting that `Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds` for `x = X(:,i);`

Comment: Ok, another mistake was that, it should be X(i.,:)

Comment: After implementing the changes above, MSE linearly _increases_ with number of iterations. As you suggested I was indexing the array incorrectly. I'm not sure which part of gradient descent is not working. Will update code above

Comment: @Rrz0 added one more minor correction.